# How to register a mouse click in SFML 2.5.1

Tags: c++, visual-studio, sfml

So, I have this code inside my game loop, which executes every frame:

```
   if (sf::Mouse::isButtonPressed(sf::Mouse::Button::Left) == true) {
                
            switch (j) {...}

   }
```

With the way this code is setup, the switch case inside the condition will end up executing every frame as long as the left mouse button is held down, which is causing me some issues...

What I want instead is for the switch case to execute after a single click, meaning after the mouse button is pressed and then released, and `sf::Mouse::isButtonPressed` seems perfect for the job, if not for the fact it's no longer a thing anymore in the current version of SFML (2.5.1) for some odd reason. *(Which is why any possible duplicates of this question that were made before this function was removed are no longer viable)*

So what I tried is this :

```
        if (sf::Mouse::isButtonPressed(sf::Mouse::Button::Left) == true) {
            if (sf::Mouse::isButtonPressed(sf::Mouse::Button::Left) == false) {

                switch (j) {...}

            }
        }
```

Thinking that the program will first check if the button is pressed, and then no longer pressed, and only execute the switch case if both conditions are respectively met, but that didn't work and now the switch case stopped executing entirely.

So, how do I get the program to execute instructions once every single mouse click, after a button is pressed and then released?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this does not hurt your code too much, use `sf::Event::MouseButtonReleased` where you poll events. This way your mouse event code will run only once.

Another solution might be to disable key repetition of the window which is something like `window.setKeyRepeatEnabled(false)`. I am not 100% sure how would you handle this tho.

Third solution is using a boolean to track your mouse button state.

Comment: OK, as for the first solution,it took some tweaking but it does work, so technically you did answer my question, but the same issue persists for some reason, now, for a fraction of a second after I release the mouse button, the switch case still executes for the few frames during that fraction, causing me the very same issue I'm trying to solve. Then I reversed the changes I made and tried the second solution, it simply didn't work, and that leaves us with the third solution which, I'm pretty sure the 'isButtonPressed' function IS already returning my mouse button state, so that's nothing new.